# Meaning of "autant en firent de leur côté"

Tags: sens, traduction

Any help is much appreciated. I'm struggling to understand the following:

> Autant en firent de leur côté les Comédiens français, et le procès fut jugé le 21 mars 1708 par le Parlement, qui donna complètement tort aux forains.

Does it mean:

> As much in taking the side of the French comedians, the trial was judged on March 21, 1708 by parliament, who ruled entirely against the forains.

The previous sentence is:

> Suivant leur habitude, les Comédiens forains formèrent immédiatement appel au Parlement et rédigèrent un mémoire justificatif de leur conduite. Autant en.."

Comment: I have edited the question to steer it away from a straight translation request, as this site does not engage in direct translations. I think though that the question should stand, as this case is quite interesting, and probably not easy to understand for non-native speakers.

Comment: Suivant leur habitude, les Comédiens français formèrent immédiatement appel au Parlement et rédigèrent un mémoire justificatif de leur conduite. Autant en firent de leur côté les Comédiens français, et le procès fut jugé le 21 mars 1708 par le Parlement, qui donna complètement tort aux forains. That seems odd to me.

Comment: @Lambie The previous sentence is: Suivant leur habitude, les Comédiens **forains** formèrent immédiatement appel au Parlement et rédigèrent un mémoire justificatif de leur conduite.

Comment: @GAM PUB Great. Thanks, so there are two groups of actors. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means:

> The french Comediéns did as much (as someone else did?) on their end, and the trial ...

(I would keep the french word *Comédiens* maybe to underscore that these are actors of the Comédie Française, most probably)

I analyze "*Autant en firent de leur côté les Comédiens français*" to mean: "_les Comédiens français en firent autant (**que quelqu'un d'autre**) de leur côté...", and the prior context should make clear what that *en* refers to.

Can you show us the sentence immediately before this one?

(NB: the OP added the sentence immediately before in his post following this question).

Answer (score 2):

The sentence seems to be old and dusty (because of an [inversion of words](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=en+firent+autant%2Cautant+en+firent&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cen%20firent%20autant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cautant%20en%20firent%3B%2Cc0) that feel unnatural). Nowaday you would more likely say something like :

> [De leur côté,] les Comédiens français en firent autant ...

"[En faire autant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_faire_autant)" means **to do the same thing**.

Comment: Yes, thank you...it's a history from the 1870s, so I'd bet many of the turns of phrase are antiquated...often I'm still able to decipher the meaning, but this one threw me off